# Slow wireless speeds with WiFi card

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, 802.11n, 802.11ac

Using Linksys Gigabit AC5400/EA9500 router with Intel AC7260

Very similar issue with this [post](https://forums.att.com/t5/Equipment/Wireless-speed-and-GigaPower/m-p/4955160#M1392)

Context here:

I'm running into the exact same problem as per the link above. However, I did turn my att router's WiFi off (as a user recommended) and that did help a lot to perhaps alleviate some congestion.

However, the only speed improvement I saw was on my iPhone 6s as my speeds went up from 250mbps to 450mbps using Speedsmart iPhone application. Like I said this was just by turning the WiFi off of the att router.

Afters seeing those results I had high hopes for my laptop. However, when testing from my Lenovo Yoga 2 laptop, Windows 10 64bit using an Intel AC7260 adapter, speeds still remained between 190-280mbps using beta.speedtest.net, speedtest.net and speedsmart.net, still no improvement at all.

I have the same Intel 7260AC card and have tried different settings with latest firmware as even recommended on the internet and Intel's own community support site. My link speed says 870mbps when I pull up properties in network wireless status form/window but I'm still only getting ~250mbps. However, hard ethernet line I get 890mbps down.

I'm using a Linksys Gigabit router model AC5400/EA9500 and I'm pretty sure everything is setup and fine tuned on that end. Seems to be an issue with the AC7260 network card since my iPhone 6s can connect at faster speeds than my Lenovo Yoga Pro 2.

Any one have the similar case and what was the solution?

Answer (score 3):

> My link speed says 870mbps when I pull up properties in network wireless status form/window but I'm still only getting ~250mbps.

The link will display the maximum speed supported, you may or may not get that speed.

You can verify a few things before moving forward:

- Are you connected to 802.11ac band? any lower band like 802.11a/b/g/n will give you lower speeds.
- check whether the connection is running on both spatial streams supported by your card? Since your card supports 2x2 MIMO.
- you can do a few ping tests to hosts in your wifi network and to the internet and see the results.

I found the [link](http://www.troublefixers.org/laptops/fix-intel-wireless-7260-ac-wifi-speed-issues-in-windows-10/679/?doing_wp_cron=1477024671.0748810768127441406250) which says that there were some problems with windows 10, but not with windows 7 or windows 8/8.1 and it explains how to solve them. You can go through that link and see if it helps.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of questions I have about your situation. That looks like an internal WiFi card when I googled the model.

1. When you use the laptop with the WiFi card that is having issues, where are you in relation to your router?
2. Is there anything between you and the router such as walls, metal, etc. How far away are you from the router?
3. Does the iPhone perform at the same speed when placed in the exact same spot as the laptop is when it has problems?
4. Is there any device connected to the router that uses a lower speed technology? A router will only work as fast as the slowest device connected.
5. Are the antenna cables properly and firmly attached to the WiFi card, and are the cables damaged in any way?
6. Is the WiFi card damaged or mishandled, have you had any other device in the PCIe slot on the laptop?

Comment: 3ft from router nothing in between. iphone 6s performs at same if not better speeds via speedtest and speedsmart apps for iphone.  i would say the iphone 6s and my yoga pro 2 with the internal intel ac7260 wifi card overall the speeds are the same.  nothing is connected to my linksys router other than my iphone6s, lenovo laptop and my mac book pro early 2013 that has a 802.11n wireless card (which gets roughly the same speed). anntenna are correctly and firmly attached. no damage that that i know of.

Comment: nor not sure if there is just too much interference in my apt complex or what. but paying for att uverse gigapower seems like a waste of $ if I can't get any speeds comparable via wireless.

Comment: Ah, yes. An apartment complex and excessive interference/bandwidth crowding is probably your issue. A directional high gain antenna would do you better off than the normal antennas. There are lots of people using the same wireless channels in antennas. I work at an ISP and that is a common complaint on wireless services in highly crowded apartments.